# Giving character spacing to text in fabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, letter-spacing

I am using fabricJS in my project, fabric version(1.6.2). Is there any property for spacing between characters? 
I have looked into this `charSpacing` property [char spacing fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/340ofdje/) but I believe it's not available for version(1.6.2), I have tried this [fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/monis/Lwvqamff/).
Is there any other way to achieve similar?

Thanks

PS: I cannot update my version because it's in completion stage and don't know what got broke.

Comment: Char spacing added in `Version_1.6.4` , [check](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-changelog-old)

Comment: Thanks for reply, can we achieve something similar in 1.6.2 ?

Comment: You can update the version, there you wont get any issue I guess. Give a try

Answer (score 0):

Char spacing got added on fabricjs 1.6.4

What you can do if you do not want to update the library, is to fork your version of fabricjs 1.6.2 and cherry pick the charsparcing commit and any other that is after it and contains some fixes.

Is a tedious process prone to errors, i would suggest to pick up last of 1.6.X branch if you think 1.7.X is too dangerous.

Comment: Thanx, that's helpful